# New mac - installed tmux but can't use mouse in for pane switching

Tags: terminal, mouse, settings, iterm, tmux

I have the required setw / setg setting for mouse in my .tmux.conf but they aren't working.

I've done `tmux source-file .tmux.conf`

I can use tmux and split windows with my remapped keys and other settings that I have such as remapping the power key ARE working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I was using tmux with the basic mac terminal app.

It *mostly* worked but a few things didn't.  The mouse functionality is an example.

The answer was that I needed to download and use iterm2 as the actual terminal app to use tmux with.

Once I did this my tmux mouse settings worked fine with it.